# Paypal recurring payment, how to update and charge outstanding balance in the middle of a cycle

Tags: paypal

I have the following scenario and I was wondering how to go about it:

1. A $10 monthly recurring payment is created, let's say starting today 11/19.
2. On 11/30 the user adds another module to the package that costs $5 more a month. All is well, I can update the recurring payment to $15 a month, so on 12/19 the user will get charged $15.
3. Since the user added this new module in the middle of a billing cycle, I would like to charge the profile the outstanding amount between 11/30 when the new package was added, and until 12/19 wen the new billing cycle kicks in (roughly that would amount to about $2.70 in this case).

I tried adding an outstanding balance when the profile is updated, however the API returns a failure message: the delinquent amount cannot be increased.

Other than cancelling the current profile and creating a new one is there any way to just update the existing one? Or if I cancel it, would the user have to reenter their credit card/ address again? I suppose I could always store this info in the paypal vault and retrieve it later.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running [BillOutstandingAmount](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/BillOutstandingAmount_API_Operation_NVP/) first?

Comment: Yup, but it failed saying "there is no outstanding balance". I wonder if it would be better to use the REST API, save the credit card to the vault, use it in the agreement, and that way I can do a one time charge if need be. Thoughts on this approach?

Comment: You don't have to use the REST API for that.  You can use Reference Transactions, which are essentially the same thing, in the classic API.  I prefer classic because it's more mature.